# How to access viewpager's fragment from activity

Tags: android, fragment

Suppose such an scenario, we have an activity and 3 fragments, like so: `MyActivity` `Frg1`, `Frg2` and `Frg3`. `Frg2` and `Frg3` are embedded into a viewPager. My needs is to trigger `Frg2` from `Frg1`. I made an interface `TriggerActivityFromFrg1` and `MyActivity` implements it, when press button in `Frg1` I call `(getActivity) triggerActivityFromFrg1.trigger()` and method `trigger()` is called in `MyActivity`, the problem is how to trigger `Frg2` from activity?

I'd like to make somehow an interface between MyActivity and Frg2.

p.s. I don't want to use eventbus.

Comment: is viewpager placed in different activity?

Comment: viewPager is in the same activity, I mentioned all components in scenario

Comment: can you post your layout files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Have your `Frg2` class *also* implement the interface:

   ```
   public class Frg2 extends Fragment implements TriggerActivityFromFrg1 {
   ```

   and implement the method

   ```
       @Override
       public void trigger() {
           if (getView() != null) {  // see comments below
               // TODO logic here
           }
       }
   ```
2. Add a field to your activity to keep track of the target fragment:

   ```
       private TriggerActivityFromFrg1 mTarget;
   ```
3. Add the register/unregister methods to the activity:

   ```
       public synchronized void registerTriggerTarget(TriggerActivityFromFrg1 listener) {
           mTarget = listener;
       }

       public synchronized void unregisterTriggerTarget(TriggerActivityFromFrg1 listener) {
           if (mTarget == listener) {
               mTarget = null;
           }
       }
   ```
4. Make the trigger method in your activity like this:

   ```
       public void trigger() {
           if (mTarget != null) {
               mTarget.trigger();
           }
       }
   ```
5. Override `onAttach()` and `onDetach()` in `Frg2` to register/unregister:

   ```
       @Override
       public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
           super.onAttach(activity);
           ((MyActivity) activity).registerTriggerTarget(this);
       }

       @Override
       public void onDetach() {
           ((MyActivity) getActivity()).unregisterTriggerTarget(this);
           super.onDetach();
       }
   ```

Congratulations, you just built your own mini event bus.

There's a reason you have to add all this code, and that's because `ViewPager` won't create fragments until it needs them.  Also it decouples `MyActivity` from `Frg2`.

Another thing to keep in mind if extending `FragmentPagerAdapter` is that the fragment will stay in memory even if the view is destroyed, so make sure you check that the fragment has a valid view, i.e. `if (getView() != null)`